# Using $filter eq query on list items using the msgraph-sdk-java

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, microsoft-graph

We have a SharePoint list of items where we would like to filter on a specific field (i.e. EMail = sample@microsoft.com) to create a list of entries. We are getting 400 errors saying invalid filter expression.

This is our list schema:

[image]

Query, where we are selecting columns FirstName (PRD First Name), Title (PRD Last Name), BRK Name (BRK_x0020_Name), and Email (E-Mail), and then filtering to where the Email equals sample@microsoft.com:

```
public ListItemCollectionPage getRecipients(){
        LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();

        requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("expand", "fields(select=FirstName,Title,BRK_x0020_Name,EMail)"));
        requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "eq(EMail,'sample@microsoft.com')"));

        ListItemCollectionRequest listRequest = graphServiceClient.sites(graphConfig.getSiteId()).lists(graphConfig.getListId()).items()
            .buildRequest(requestOptions);
        
        System.out.println(listRequest.getRequestUrl());

        return listRequest.get();
}
```

The URL generated is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{side-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields%28select%3DFirstName%2CTitle%2CBRK_x0020_Name%2CEMail%29&%24filter=eq%28EMail%2C%27sample%40microsoft.com%27%29
```

Stack trace:

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: BadRequest
Error message: Invalid filter clause

400 : Bad Request
[...]

 

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromResponse(GraphServiceException.java:419) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.14.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromResponse(GraphServiceException.java:378) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.14.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:512) ~[microsoft-graph-core-2.0.14.jar:na]
```

What exactly is invalid about this request?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your filter to:

```
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("filter", "fields/EMail eq 'sample@microsoft.com'"));
```

You may get an error similar to,

> "Field 'Email' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists."

If you get this error, you need to add a header to the request with the key of Prefer and the value of `HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`.

I looked but I was unable to find any official documentation from Microsoft on the use of this header.

Comment: I had a similar problem. This has worked for me!